# Format decimal as US currency

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

```
<%= Math.Round(netValue)%>
```

One example of it's output could be -1243313

How do I make sure it's formatted as US currency (with the '$', correct commas, etc.)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<%=string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033), "{0:C}", Math.Round(netValue)) %>
```

(1033 is the locale id for the 'en-us' culture)

Comment: you could also do *Math.Round(netValue).ToString("{0:C}", new CultureInfo("en-US"))* imo it looks cleaner.

Comment: I would seriously consider replacing 1033 with "en-US" for enhanced readability.

Comment: @Pete - Hmmm... being french, I read 1033 as easily as en-US :-)

Comment: And I am also very familiar with it being British (becasue despite what the Americans think en-US is not the same as en-GB!), but I still think a local string is easier to read in source than a magic number, regadless of how familiar a magic number it is.

Answer (score 3):

If the thread culture happens to already be en-US, then you don't need to specify it.

```
<%= Math.Round(netValue).ToString("C") %>
```

Otherwise, to get the culture for the United States, first create a culture object.

```
CultureInfo usaCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You can then pass that to the ToString method on the decimal object.

```
<%= Math.Round(netValue).ToString("C", usaCulture) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format`'s currency code `C` like so :

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39;
string output = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Edit: If internationalization is an issue, you may want to take a look at [localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk.aspx) as well.

Comment: Link is broken. I think this will do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292205(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: stack overflow should not just be a collection of links. At least quote the relevant text from the page, leaving the link for further reading.